# Multiple callbacks in same async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If you have more than one callback in an asynchronous function, will it exit the function on the first execution of a callback, similar to a return statement, or will it continue on?

```
function handler(conn, callback){

    if (conn === true){
        callback('found');
    }

    callback('not found');

});
```

Comment: Callbacks are just functions.  There is no magic surrounding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will continue on, unless you `return callback()`